# Ordenar array en JS o PHP multivalues

Tags: php, javascript

Tengo la siguiente tabla en este orden. Esta tabla la envió mediante JS a mi controlador para luego procesar la data y imprimir un PDF. **Pero me gustaría ordenar agrupando mediante los nombres, tal como en los indices que agregue o que ordene los trabajadores.**

```
┌──────┬───────┬──────┬─────────────┐
│ Order│ Act1  | Act2 │ Act3 │ Act4 │
├──────┼───────┼──────┼──────│──────┤
│ 001  │  Mark │ Mark │      │      | ->4
│ 001  │  Juan │      │      │      | ->2
│ 002  │       │      │ Mark │ Mark | ->5
│ 003  │       │ Erik │      │      | ->1
│ 003  │  Mark │      │      │ Mark | ->6
│ 004  │  Juan │      │      │      | ->3
└──────┴───────┴──────┴──────┴──────┘
```

Mi function en JS.

```
function reporte_pdf(){

 var data_array = [];
 var table = $('#table_main').DataTable();
 table.rows().every(function(){
     var row = this.data();//store every row data in a variable
     data_array.push({
         "orden": row[0],
         "Act1":  row[1],
         "Act2":  row[2],
         "Act3":  row[3],
         "Act4":  row[4],
     });
 });
 $.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>pdf_reporte/index",
   data: {
     "data_array": data_array,
   },
   dataType: "json",
   cache: false,
   success: function(response) {
    window.open('<?php echo base_url() ?>csv/reportes/' + response + '.pdf', '_blank');
   }
   });
}
```

En php recomiendan `usort`, pero necesito una forma de ordenar multifuncional. Nose si una forma en PHP o JS que me recomienden. Espero haberme explicado bien

```
usort($data, function ($a, $b) {
    return $b['Act1'] <=> $a['Act1'];
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según lo que esperas recibir y que pones en la parte derecha de la tabla, solo necesitas concatenar primero todos los nombres y orden al final, que es lo que vas a usar para [ordenar](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), de preferencia, usando [localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare), por si hubiera caracteres especiales.

```js
let data = [
  {
    "orden": "001",
    "Act1": "Mark",
    "Act2": "Mark",
    "Act3": "",
    "Act4": ""
  },
  {
    "orden": "001",
    "Act1": "Juan",
    "Act2": "",
    "Act3": "",
    "Act4": ""
  },
  {
    "orden": "002",
    "Act1": "",
    "Act2": "",
    "Act3": "Mark",
    "Act4": "Mark"
  },
  {
    "orden": "003",
    "Act1": "",
    "Act2": "Erik",
    "Act3": "",
    "Act4": ""
  },
  {
    "orden": "003",
    "Act1": "Mark",
    "Act2": "",
    "Act3": "",
    "Act4": "Mark"
  },
  {
    "orden": "004",
    "Act1": "Juan",
    "Act2": "",
    "Act3": "",
    "Act4": ""
  }
];

data.sort((a, b) => {
    // Concatenar elementos
    let aConcat = (a.Act1 + a.Act2 + a.Act3 + a.Act4 + a.orden).trim();
    let bConcat = (b.Act1 + b.Act2 + b.Act3 + b.Act4 + b.orden).trim();
    return aConcat.localeCompare(bConcat);
});

console.log(data);
```

También lo puedes hacer desde PHP con la función [usort()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.usort.php), concatenando igual que en Javascript y comparando las cadenas con [strcasecmp](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.strcasecmp.php); aunque creo más conveniente enviar el arreglo ordenado desde Javascript... Cuestión de preferencias.

Comment: Muchas gracias, consulta y en PHP como seria?